# Generate future reservation dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql

EDIT: As to avoid confusion because of the word "tables" having two meanings: Every time I refer to "100 tables", I'm refering to 100 physical tables in a single business available for booking each day.

I've come to the conclusion that for a table-booking system such as the one I'm trying to develop, a single MySQL table with a unique index made up of tableid and date will suffice, meaning I can have my table reservations in a single table and according to my research store at least +100 years into the future without any performance issues. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Further explained: I have a set of let's say 100 bookable tables just to not run out of tables (for this project I will rarely require more than 30, but you never know). Each table is numbered 1-100 and the combination of table number (tableid) and the date is a unique entry in the database. I.e. you can only have the row of table 4 on date 2014-06-18 once. That's fine, and I can just generate 100 rows for each day for the next 100 years, yes?

I use a BIGINT as Primary Key for each row with Auto-Increment starting at 1.

Now - what is the easiest solution to generating all these rows in MySQL? Each row just needs to have `INSERT INTO tables (TABLEID,DATE) VALUES ([id],[date])` as the rest of the fields populate by default. Dates can just start from today as this project has no business in the past. I did some Googling but cannot really figure out the difference between a script and a stored procedure, and the variable declaration for each seems to be different and confuses me a bit.

This should be fairly simply though, and the question is also aimed at whether this approach is a good practice or not.

Thanks

Comment: That sounds like a bad DB design. Why do you need 100 tables? One for each year?

Comment: You are confusing tables with physical tables.

I have 100 physical tables available for booking stored in a single MySQL table.

Comment: Ah - tables in a restaurant. OK.

Comment: For instance, yes. I've updated the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: Normally you would not pre-populate tables which seems to be what you want to do. Just insert a record on demand.

Comment: The problem is I need the array delivered by PHP to have a fixed size in order not to crash the client software. For instance if I just insert and only book table 6,7,8,12,15 and 22, the array will have a size of 6 but needs to have a size of say 30 in order for the client software to work properly.

Comment: Then add missing entries in PHP, no need to store them.

Comment: How would I go about that? I need the array to be like:

Table 1:
Name: name
Guest count: count
Price: price

From table 1 to table 30 etc., regardless if I can find them in MySQL.

Comment: But I assume that's a different question.

Comment: I ended up just doing a php script to insert the rows I need. I know this is not a proper answer to the question, but it got me the results I wanted. I have no issues with pre-populating tables as the data I work with is sparse.